# vim-gtk3 and vim-athena fail to install on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: package-management, dependencies, vim

I tried to install Vim with GUI on Ubuntu 22.04 but failed.
I get the following errors when I run `sudo apt install vim-gtk3` or `sudo apt install vim-athena`.  It seems both packages need to be rebuilt with updated pre-prerequisites.

```
$ sudo apt install vim-gtk3

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 vim-gtk3 : Depends: vim-common (= 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.1) but 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed

            Depends: vim-runtime (= 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.1) but 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ sudo apt install vim-athena

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 vim-athena : Depends: vim-common (= 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.1) but 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed

              Depends: vim-runtime (= 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.1) but 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Did you try running `sudo apt update` before trying to install these packages?

Comment: Version `2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.2` is currently in the `jammy-proposed` repository. Do not enable -proposed sources unless you already know how to solve little problems like this. -proposed is for testing only, daily use is strongly discouraged. Fix your sources.